# How to display block text based on div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display text block based on div height.

Should look like this:

```
If (height >= 3000) {
  display #block2
} else {
  nothing
}
```

I tried so far:

```js
$(function() {
  var $block1 = $('#block1');
  $block1.html('Div style set as "height: 3000px;"')
    .append('<p>Height (.height() returns) : ' + $block1.height() + ' [Just Height]</p>')
});
```

```css
div { font-size: 0.9em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="block1" style="height: 3000px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="block2">example text (display this block)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question further?

Comment: `if ( $block1.height() > 3000)` ?

Comment: `I'm trying to display text block based on div height.` So you want to display the height of the div, inside that div, as a text ? and while the height changes, the text should change? i don't understand :)

Comment: Don't use .html on your block1 element, it will overwrite your block2, this is why it's not showing when you do your if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - you have the height so all you need to do is show your div in the if:

Below I put your height into the if statement and then show block 2 based on block 1's height.  Block 2 starts off as hidden with your css

```js
var $block1 = $('#block1'),
    $block2 = $('#block2');

if ($block1.height() >= 3000) {
   $block2.show();                // show block 2 if block 1 height (not including padding or margin) >= 3000
}
```

```css
div { font-size: 0.9em; }

#block2 {
    display:none;  /*start off hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1" style="height: 3000px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="block2">example text (display this block)</div>
</div>
```